# Finder Advanced Search - Only within directory

Tags: finder, search

I have an advanced Finder search criteria to show everything modified within the last X days. I'm not seeing an option that would let me restrict this search to only files within a specific directory (and sub-directories).

The Finder preference that controls where to search does not apply to advanced searches.

Answer (score 1):

It seems once you've saved a search, you can't change what folder(s) it scopes. I recreated the search from the directory I wanted to include, and that worked.

Comment: tbh, if it's one directory, just sorting by date modified would be a pretty simple alternative.

Comment: @Tetsujin - wanted it to include sub-directories and those files too